# Add class to active menu items with internal anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a list of menu items consisting of internal anchors. I'm trying to add an .active class to the selected item. It seems to work on load but when clicking a new item in that same page it doesn't.

When clicking a new menu item, I would like to remove all other active classes and add this class to the clicked item.

Sounds pretty simple, but I can't make it work. 
I created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrzpo8a0/), but it doesn't show the issue correctly, since I can't add hashes to the url.

However, maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

**JS:**

```
function setActiveLinks() {
  var current = location.pathname;
  $('.bs-docs-sidenav li a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Get hash value
    var $hash = location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf('#') + 1);
    if ($this.attr('href') == '#' + $hash) {
      $this.parent().addClass('active');
    }
  })
}

setActiveLinks();

$('#leftmenu li a').click(function() {
$('#leftmenu li').removeClass('active');
  setActiveLinks();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav bs-docs-sidenav">
  <li>
    <a href="#download">Download</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#whats-included">What's included</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#whats-included-precompiled">Precompiled</a></li>
      <li><a href="#whats-included-source">Source code</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#grunt">Compiling CSS and JavaScript</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#grunt-installing">Installing Grunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#grunt-commands">Available Grunt commands</a></li>
      <li><a href="#grunt-troubleshooting">Troubleshooting</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong selector to bind click event on anchor element. also you don't need to call `setActiveLinks()` function(which sets class based on href) here.

You can use context of clicked anchor element to traverse to parent li and add class active in it:

```
var $navLIs = $('.nav li')
$navLIs.find('a').click(function() {
  $navLIs.removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/61qck9ur/)**